# How to check what user did when they login through WinSCP?

Tags: linux, winscp

I need to check what user did when they login through WinSCP.

I have tried this commands:

```
$ last
$ w
$ pinky
$ who mom likes
...
```

But I can not find a way to answer my question above.
I'm still searching a possible solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pinky` didn't do it? that's a shocker

Comment: @janos: Yes, it not show WinSCP session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure `sshd` full logging (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging)
and after you will see all user actions on server side.

Comment: I will keep reading. However, I wonder is there any way to show  a little session information?

Comment: because any user in `passwd` could login you could use `users` to see  current users on the server

Comment: Thanks Zagorulkin Dmitry. Maybe I need to update my question. I really want to see the past session and current session.